# How to open google play store and show my app reviews section?

Tags: android

In my app I'm asking a user to rate the app. If he agrees I'm opening google play store with sth like this:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that it opens google play store, shows my app but user has to scroll manually to the rate section.

Is there a way to show the rate section directly so he doesn't have to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to show the rate section directly so he doesn't have to scroll?

No you can't.